# Microsoft access Navigate record Combo Box

Tags: ms-access, search, vba

I am creating a form in Microsoft Access. In this form I want a user to be able to input a [Tag] number and have it redirect them to the record for that Tag.

I keep getting a Data mismatch error every time I try to search for a record. 
The tags have 2 formats 1st format is six numbers [123456] second format is three letters followed by six numbers [ABC123456].

```
Private Sub RF_SEARCH_BY_TAG_COMBO_BOX_AfterUpdate()
' Find the record that matches the control.
Dim rs As Object

Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
rs.FindFirst "[Tag]=" & Str(Nz(Me![RF_SEARCH_BY_TAG_COMBO_BOX], 0))
If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Komakino, since Tag must be a string, rewrite the `FindFirst` line as:

```
rs.FindFirst "[Tag]='" & Nz(Me.RF_SEARCH_BY_TAG_COMBO_BOX.Value, "") & "'"
```

Three fixes:

1. The search value is properly quoted
2. The `Nz()` function defaults to an empty string `""`
3. The `RF_SEARCH_BY_TAG_COMBO_BOX` is referred to using dot notation